# "Invert" the output to list everything that is not printed/listed at this time

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Playing around with SQL. I am trying to list the name of every country where all cities have an individual population count of less than 100 000 people.

The below code gives me every country that have a city that has more then 100 000  people, so by terms i am trying to "Invert" the output to list everything that is not printed/listed at this time.

Suggestions?

```
Select distinct country.Name from country,city
where city.CountryCode = country.Code and city.population > 100000;
```

Comment: city.population < 100000;

Comment: I think I not understood the question entirely but why not just city.population < 100.000 to retrieve the other part of the set?

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to handing this uses aggregation and `having`:

```
select co.Name
from country co left join
     city ci
     on ci.CountryCode = co.Code 
group by co.Name
having coalesce(max(ci.population), 0) <= 100000;
```

The `coalesce()` and `left join` take into account countries that have no cities.

For reference, the equivalent query for the version in your question:

```
select co.Name
from country co left join
     city ci
     on ci.CountryCode = co.Code 
group by co.Name
having max(ci.population) >= 100000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be it.

```
      SELECT name FROM country WHERE Population IN
      (
      SELECT population FROM city WHERE Population < 100000
      )
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it includes countries which have cities with more than 100000 people

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all countries which do not have a city with population > 100000 - something like this should do it:

```
SELECT country.Name FROM country
WHERE country.CountryCode 
  NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT city.CountryCode FROM city WHERE city.population > 100000)
```

Answer (score -1):

As most other comments already said, flip the `>` to `<=`. I also rewrote your query to use a join, you might want to look at those too.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country.Name 
FROM country INNER JOIN city ON (city.CountryCode = country.Code)
WHERE city.population <= 100000;
```

Comment: This does not confirm that ALL the cities in the country has a population under 100000, only that at-least ONE